# Webkit Tap Highlight Color Larger than Links

Tags: javascript, css, ios, uiwebview, webkit

Within a UIWebView in an iOS app I have events firing in javascript when a link is pressed. There is also a grey box that typically appears over links when they are tapped. The `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` css property.

However, the hit area that activates this grey box is different from the element frame according to javascript. The result is that if I tap a certain distance from links the tap highlight color is activated but the event is not fired as you expect it to when you get this feedback.

Is there any way to correct the frame that activates the highlight color? or perhaps there is an easier way to just disable that and provide similar feedback another way?